# Post Data in Json Format Android Error 404

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I am posting data in json Format to server but I am getting response status 404,
please let me know how to fixed,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("email", uemail);

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            Log.e("value send",json);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());


            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
           httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
           httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

thanks

Comment: The HTTP-Status Code 404 stands for "NOT FOUND", so you provide the wrong URL
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Agree with the above. Have you double checked the URL? try loading it through a browser.

Comment: yes I have check URL is perfect

Comment: Insert more code. Your provided code is ok, but your URL or Server implementation is probably wrong.